# Simple RESTful service using Jersey and Eclipse

Tags: web-services, rest

I have been trying to create a simple RESTful service using Jersey and Eclipse. I have copied the code from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/#ibm-pcon. When i tried to run the service i got HTTP Status 404- /Jersey/

Service: `HelloResource.java`

```
package sample.hello.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Jersey</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>sample.hello.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Kindly help in running the above service successfully...donno where i have gone wrong.

Comment: Which URL did you try to access? What gives 404?

Comment: The URL is most important as Lutz said.  Did you use `http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/hello` (if you deployed as `Jersey.war` for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use following URL to access resource,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/<app_name>/rest/hello
```

Following site containing good/simple example, you can give a try if above is not working. 
http://lasithtechavenue.blogspot.com/2012/12/implementing-rest-service-with-java.html